# Disable WAL in OrientDB through Java API

Tags: orientdb, wal

We have an OrientDB graph database and a daily scheduler which performs massive insertions in the database using the Java API. For this reason, we would like to disable WAL from the Java code when performing these insertions, otherwise the size of the WAL file will be huge in a short amount of time.

We already know that is possible to disable WAL permanently by editing some OrientDB configurations, but we don't want to make this choice.

We have seen that there is a closed issue on the github repository of OrientDB, which suggests the following solution:

```
private void reopenWithWALSetTo(final boolean useWAL) {
    db.getStorage().close(true, false);
    db.close();
    OGlobalConfiguration.USE_WAL.setValue(useWAL);
    db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(dbURL);
    db.open("admin", "admin");
}
```

The problem is that we are not using an instance of ODatabaseDocumentTx when opening the connection with the database. In fact, since we are using a graph DB, we use OrientGraphFactory in the following way:

```
factory = new OrientGraphFactory("url", "username", "password");
graph = factory.getTx();
```

It is possible to obtain an instance of ODatabaseDocumentTx in the following way:

```
db = graph.getRawGraph();
```

But then, after having close the instance of ODatabaseDocumentTx, it is not possible to reopen the connection with our graph db.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the journal (WAL) for some operations where reliability is not necessary, starting OrientDB with this Java option:

```
-Dstorage.useWAL=false
```

https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Write-Ahead-Log.html